# How to query a CTE using a select statement with a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to return all incidents within a certain time start and end date and send the data to my application.

The server is in GMT and most of the users of this application are in EST so I'm doing a -4 hour conversion using dateadd.

The thing is, let's say the user puts in start and end date of '03-23-2019', the query will return an incident with a date and time of '03-22-2019 9:00PM'.

The incident outside of the date range is being returned because of that time conversion I'm doing during the select statement.

That incident dated '03-22-2019 9:00PM' is actually in that database as '03-23-2019 1:00AM'.

So far I've tried using a CTE to run the initial query that does the conversion and then I'm attempting to query that CTE to pull the dates that meet the criteria.

```
WITH incidents AS (
SELECT dv_u_store as LoginID, convert(varchar(30),dateadd(hh,-4,sys_created_on),22) as Submit_Date,
COALESCE(number,'') as Incident_Number, dv_incident_state as [Status], '' as  Product_Name, 
dv_priority as Priority, dv_short_description as [Summary]
From dbo.incident
WHERE dv_u_store IN ('004188') AND sys_created_on >= '04-23-2019' AND sys_created_on < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '04-26-2019')
)
SELECT *
FROM incidents
WHERE submit_date >= '04-23-2019' AND submit_date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '04-26-2019')
ORDER BY submit_date DESC
```

**Start Date:** 04-23-2019

**End Date:** 04-26-2019 + 1 Day (04-27-2019)

So in this case the CTE alone returns 4 rows:

04/25/19 1:40AM

04/24/19 4:57PM

04/23/19 1:40AM

04/22/19 8:18PM

I then have another select statement referencing that CTE which has a WHERE clause that passes the start and end date again.

The thing is, that select statement is NOT filtering out the last entry of '04-22-19' which is outside of the start and end date range.

How can I query a CTE with the start and end date to filter out anything that no longer meets the criteria after that 4 hour conversion?

So that it only returns:

04/25/19 1:40AM

04/24/19 4:57PM

04/23/19 1:40AM

**I'm also open to doing a better time conversion. I just need the time of each incident to be in EST rather than GMT when it gets returned to my application.**

**EDIT**

```
WITH incidents AS (
SELECT dv_u_store as LoginID, convert(VARCHAR(30), dateadd(hh,-4,sys_created_on), 22) as Submit_Date,
COALESCE(number,'') as Incident_Number, dv_incident_state as [Status], '' as  Product_Name, 
dv_priority as Priority, dv_short_description as [Summary]
From dbo.incident
WHERE dv_u_store IN ('004188') AND sys_created_on >= CAST('04-23-2019' AS datetime) AND sys_created_on < cast(DATEADD(DAY, 1, '04-26-2019') AS datetime)
)
SELECT *
FROM Incidents
WHERE submit_date >= cast('04-23-2019' AS datetime) AND submit_date < cast(DATEADD(DAY, 1, '04-26-2019') AS DATETIME)
ORDER BY submit_date DESC
```

As suggested by the comments I've changed the conversions around. Now during the where clause I'm casting those strings as DATETIME.

Comment: Have you tried adding the 4 hour conversion to your parameters (not converting them to strings)?

Comment: you've converted the date time within the CTE to a varchar... you'd need to reconvert it to a datetime to do a proper comparison.  As it stands, you are doing string comparisons.

Comment: @user681574 This worked. I kept the initial CONVERT in the select statement and then used CAST for the date variables to convert them to DATETIME.

Comment: @LuisCazares I removed that conversion in the beginning and it messed up the format of the dates. I ended up leaving it and then converting the dates in the where clauses to DATETIME format and it seemed to work.

Comment: That still doesn't look correct.  You converted to a string in the CTE then tried to filter it as a date in the where clause.  If you really want to see a date with 4 hours difference, converted to some output style- then do so in the SELECT clause.

Comment: @Zorkolot I believe it works because it is implicitly casting the other side to a datetime in this case.  If this is for more than a few thousand rows, it would be better to keep them as datetime in the CTE and then format the final output.

Comment: @user681574 Actually, is the CTE even required?  OP used the same exact date filters twice- once in the CTE, once in the query.  If submit_date is a date datatype, it should be manipulated as a date (and we don't need to cast a string to a date to specify a date), not in a roundabout way like this.

Answer (score 0):

Take this for a spin...

```
DECLARE
    @begdate DATETIME = '2019-04-23',
    @enddate DATETIME = '2019-04-26';

SELECT 
    @begdate = DATEADD(HOUR, -4, @begdate),
    @enddate = DATEADD(HOUR, 20, @enddate); -- rather than adding a day and adjusting for UTC, just add 20 hours...

SELECT
    LoginID = i.dv_u_store,
    Submit_Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR (30), DATEADD(hh, -4, i.sys_created_on), 22),
    Incident_Number = COALESCE(i.number, ''),
    Status = i.dv_incident_state,
    Product_Name = '',
    Priority = i.dv_priority,
    Summary = i.dv_short_description
FROM
    dbo.incident i
WHERE
    i.dv_u_store IN ('004188')
    AND i.sys_created_on >= @begdate
    AND i.sys_created_on < @enddate;
```